# RTF adding <span> tags in CME

Tags: 2011, cme, 2011-sp1

In a Rich Text Field of a Component I add in some text for e.g. "This is my first line. This will be my second line.". I then hit Enter after "line.".

At this point when I view the source, I see the following:

```
<p>This is my first line.&#160;</p>
<p>This will be my second line.</p>
```

As expected.

However, now I go back into the design tab and click backspace to essentially have all the text in one line and this is how my source becomes:

```
<p>This is my first line.&#160;<span style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Verdana;">This will be my second line.</span></p>
```

Where are these `span` tags coming from? How can I remove them to just keep the `p` tags? We are using Tridion 2011 SP1. Also, if it helps at all, I have tried replicating the same issue on another Tridion environment and this doesn't happen. So I believe this is a configuration thing, but don't really know where to start.

### UPDATE 1

The XSLT for *one* of the Schema fields is shown below.

```
<stylesheet xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" cdata-section-elements="script"></output>
<template match="/ | node() | @*">
    <copy>
        <apply-templates select="node() | @*"></apply-templates>
    </copy>
</template>
<template match="*[      (self::br or self::p or self::div)     and      normalize-space(translate(., &apos; &apos;, &apos;&apos;)) = &apos;&apos;     and      not(@*)     and      not(processing-instruction())     and      not(comment())     and      not(*[not(self::br) or @* or * or node()])     and      not(following::node()[not(         (self::text() or self::br or self::p or self::div)        and         normalize-space(translate(., &apos; &apos;, &apos;&apos;)) = &apos;&apos;        and         not(@*)        and         not(processing-instruction())        and         not(comment())        and         not(*[not(self::br) or @* or * or node()])       )])     ]">
    <!-- ignore all paragraphs and line-breaks at the end that have nothing but (non-breaking) spaces and line breaks -->
</template>
<template match="br[parent::div and not(preceding-sibling::node()) and not(following-sibling::node())]">
    <!-- Chrome generates <div><br/></div>. Renders differently in different browsers. Replace it with a non-breaking space -->
    <text> </text>
</template>
```

There are other RTFs that have the same issue too.

### UPDATE 2

I have also looked at the XSLTs in the following location `\TRIDION_HOME\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\web\WebUI\Core\Controls\FormatArea\XSLTs`. I've compared these to working versions and both sets are identical.

### UPDATE 3

Further to Robs comment, I have tested this across different browsers and can confirm this only happens in Chrome - all other browsers are fine.

Comment: Could you post your XSLT for the schema field? Maybe something weird going on in that?

Comment: Thanks Rob, done. If it helps, I have compared this XSLT to a schema field of another Tridion environment where this problem doesn't exist and it's the same. So I don't think it's an XSLT issue. One thing I have noticed is, after doing a comparison of the two, the Allowed Styles tab contains different items. Not sure if this would cause span tags to appear?

Comment: Is there anything different in the schema field?  Specifically, have you disabled any of the formatting features?

Comment: Hi JDubz, I disabled every option in Allowed Styles and Allowed Actions (may have went over the top doing this), but the problem still exists. Only difference between the schema fields is, the one that works (bear in mind this is a totally different environment to that which doesn't work) has a different "height rows" option. But I don't see how changing the height would be the cause of this.

Comment: Could this be a browser issue? Are you checking in the same browser? Have the same hotfixes been applied to both environments?

Comment: Hi Rob, didn't think of this! Yes it seems to be a browser issue. I don't see the problem when using IE or Firefox. Problem only occurs in Chrome. I'm still confused though as the working environment works in all three browsers. Both environments have the same hotfix roll up 1.

Comment: Anyone got any idea how this could be browser related? XSLT is same on both environments, that being in Tridion and the XSLTs that are located at TRIDION_HOME - could it be a Tridion config issue?

Comment: If this is working differently for different browsers then I would suggest that it is a bug in the RTF Editor that is used by the CME.  I would suggest that you raise this with Tridion Support.

Comment: IT appears the the CKEditor also suffered from this issue:  https://github.com/RomanMinkin/webkit-span-fix

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply a template match for removing set of html tags which needs to be separated by Pipe symbol (`|`) such as `span|em|p|br|i`

### Example:

```
<!-- Remove disallowed elements but keep its children -->
<template match="span|em">
    <apply-templates/>
</template>
```

Your Filter XSLT will look like this

```
<stylesheet xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" cdata-section-elements="script"/>
    <template match="/ | node() | @*">
        <copy>
            <apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </copy>
    </template>
    <template match="*[      (self::br or self::p or self::div)     and      normalize-space(translate(., &apos; &apos;, &apos;&apos;)) = &apos;&apos;     and      not(@*)     and      not(processing-instruction())     and      not(comment())     and      not(*[not(self::br) or @* or * or node()])     and      not(following::node()[not(         (self::text() or self::br or self::p or self::div)        and         normalize-space(translate(., &apos; &apos;, &apos;&apos;)) = &apos;&apos;        and         not(@*)        and         not(processing-instruction())        and         not(comment())        and         not(*[not(self::br) or @* or * or node()])       )])     ]">
        <!-- ignore all paragraphs and line-breaks at the end that have nothing but (non-breaking) spaces and line breaks -->
    </template>
    <template match="br[parent::div and not(preceding-sibling::node()) and not(following-sibling::node())]">
        <!-- Chrome generates <div><br/></div>. Renders differently in different browsers. Replace it with a non-breaking space -->
        <text> </text>
    </template>
    <!-- Remove disallowed elements but keep its children -->
    <template match="span|em">
        <apply-templates/>
    </template>
</stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Siva. Only thing is that doesn't explain why the other Tridion environments I have tested against work fine and don't have this problem? The Filtering XSLT on other environments are the same to the one I am having issues with.

Comment: @IbrarHussain: That's weird. Let me think, in the mean while try my suggestion.

Comment: I did try your suggestion, restarted the COM+. Didn't work.

Comment: @IbrarHussain: I have tested your Filter XSLT which is working fine as expected. I suspect that you are looking on different schema/field and testing on another schema/field. Just check it out.

Comment: Hi Siva, I'm definitely looking at the right field and testing the correct one too. I did suspect this but have tried again just now, same problem.